# Why does this print statement print my variables on new line each?

Tags: python, printing

When I run this statement, each variable prints on a new line.

```
print(last_name,",",first_name,",",town,",",state,",",age)
```

My goal is to have each variable print after the prior one on the same line. After doing some research I found that the `end=""` can do this.

However, when I add this to the end of my print statement it only combines the last 2 variables into one line. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, Please read [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) to learn how to ask a good homework question.

Comment: `print(last_name,",",first_name,",",town,",",state,",",age)` the result will be in same line..

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I bet your variables themselves contain newline characters.

Comment: Show us how those variables are created.  (Are you reading them from a file?)

Answer (score 0):

After age add the following syntax:

, end=" ")

See link below for example.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/print-single-and-multiple-variable-in-python

If this does not work can you please repost the code with the end statement.
Another option is to test just your first two variables with the end = “ “ to see if it runs, then as it runs add one more variable and test again to see that it works. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @Julien has stated it is likely the case that your variables contain `\n` at the end of each variable. A way that you could remove that character and print in the format that you wanted is with the following:

This assumes that all elements are strings.

```
# first taking all of the items in a list replace the \n character with nothing then joining the list with a comma between each element
print(','.join([x.replace('\n', '') for x in [last_name, first_name, town, state, age]]))
```